# SDL Tridion UI 2012 throwing error 'GetSiteEditItemConfiguration' could not be activated

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We have installed SDL Tridion UI 2012 and getting SDTridion button on top left side. 
 On Clicking the button SiteEdit UI interface is coming properly with disabled options and it is throwing below error in message centre -

> The requested service,
>   'http://localhost/WebUI/Models/SiteEdit/Services/Services.svc/GetSiteEditItemConfiguration'
>   could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for
>   more information.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you "See the server's diagnostic trace logs"? Are you loading on the same server as Tridion is running? (your URL says "localhost")

Comment: Yes, I am loading on the same server, as CMS, CDA both are configured on this server and we are considering it as presentation server (staging) also. Are we wrong in that case, Could you please confirm me on earlier basis please?

Comment: It might something as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428360/i-set-up-my-sdl-tridion-2011-instance-to-run-with-multiple-host-headers-and-now but not sure until you get more data about the error - check your windows event viewer and try to look at the trace logs as suggested by the error message.

Comment: Check in your browser's debugging tools what the full response is to that `GetSiteEditItemConfiguration` call. It will tell you why the WCF service can not be activated.

Comment: Thanks,Nuno and Frank for your help. I was not able to provide server's diagnostic trace log due to not allowed to installed the Windows SDK at the server. Thanks to Frank to provide another option for same.

Answer (score 3):

Problem get resolved by uninstalling and installing the set up again.Problem may be due to installing the setup before setting up the session preview Content Delivery Web service. Thanks to all helping hands for assisting me even in weekend.